# Disable Firebase hosting github deploy

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to disable firebase hosting. I currently have GitHub deploys enabled, so when I push, firebase hosting gets another deployment.

I disabled hosting with

```bash
firebase hosting:disable
```

But then it re-enables when I do `git push`.

How do I disable this? I've searched and can't find a way to **disable** this feature -- only enable.

Also there's nothing related in

```bash
firebase -h
```

Comment: This looks like a feature of github, not firebase. Did you enable github auto-deployments when you initialized the project?

Comment: @dcts, yep, followed these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/github-integration

Comment: oh ok then it should be failry easy to disable with this guide: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/disabling-and-enabling-a-workflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When initializing github auto deploy with firebase, the following things happen under the hood:

1. a github action is created (auto deploy)
2. whenevery you deploy with `firebase deploy:hosting` the action is triggered
3. whenevery you deploy with `git push ...` the action is triggered

Disabling the hosting with `firebase deploy:hosting` only disables the action when deploying from firebase, not from github. To remove that action from github too follow [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/disabling-and-enabling-a-workflow):

[image]

Comment: Is point number 2 correct? If I directly deploy to Firebase hosting using the firebase-tools CLI command `firebase deploy --only hosting` then it does not go through Github so how does the Github Action get triggered? Also `firebase deploy:hosting` is not a real command and I suspect you mean `firebase deploy --only hosting`